# arc4random_uniform( ) and different behaviour with arm64

Tags: ios, arm, arc4random

Given the following code
`NSInteger random = arc4random_uniform(3) - 1;`

this code compiled for armv7, armv7 and i386 (tested on an iPhone 5 and iOS Simulator) produce an uniform distribution of the element {-1,0,1}; but when compiled for arm64 and run on iPhone 5s it produce {4294967295, 0, 1}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

arc4random_uniform returns an an unsigned int, - 1 on it will return you to the largest 32 bit integer size 4294967295.

You'll need to cast arc4random_uniform(3) into an int before you can -1 on it.

**Example of the 64-bit 32-bit unsigned/signed integer problem**

*Rule 4: The sum of a signed value and an unsigned value of the same size is an unsigned value.*

```
int a=-2;
unsigned int b=1;
long c = a + b;
long long d=c; // to get a consistent size for printing.
```

printf("%lld\n", d);
Problem: When this code is executed in the 32-bit runtime, the result is -1 (0xffffffff). When the code is run in the 64-bit runtime, the result is 4294967295 (0x00000000ffffffff), which is probably not what you were expecting.

Cause: Why does this happen? First, the two numbers are added. A signed value plus an unsigned value results in an unsigned value (rule 4). Next, that value is promoted to a larger type. This promotion does not cause sign extension.

Solution: To fix this problem in a 32-bit-compatible way, cast b to a long integer. This cast forces the non-sign-extended promotion of b to a 64-bit type prior to the addition, thus forcing the signed integer to be promoted (in a signed fashion) to match. With that change, the result is the expected -1.

[stolen from the apple 64-Bit Transition Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH3-SW1)

Comment: I agree but this doesn't explain with, for instance, it works fine in the simulator.

Comment: Simulator uses a different compiler, arm64 uses a different instructions set when compiling. I'm certainly not qualified to go into greater detail on this, but it seems armv7 and i386's compilers are autocasting for you whereas arm64 isn't.

Comment: and also the iPhone 5 seems to auto cast. I understand that problem with the unsigned, what I want to understand is why this "auto cast" is happening or not.

Comment: Sorry I got it wrong, an explanation is in the apple 64-bit transition guide.

Comment: Thanks man, totally forgot to check the 64-bit transition guide